# peticiones en Laravel Mucho a mucho

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo una galería de imágenes, el cual usa etiquetas para filtrar en resultados de búsqueda, mi problema es que no consigo dar con las sentencia:
yo al buscador le paso la id de cada etiqueta, mas o menos así:
`$tag_id= [1,2];`
la idea es que me devuelva solo las imágenes  que tengan las **dos etiquetas** y no solo una esta es la base de datos

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ4Rx.png
esta era la sentencia que estaba probando:
 `$l = Imagen::when($tag_id,function ($query,$tag_id){ $imagens_id = DB::table('imagen_tag')->select('imagen_id') ->whereIn('tag_id',$tag_id); return $query->whereIn('id',$imagens_id);})->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer pruebas en tinker ya que tinker te proporciona una interfaz comoda de probar las consultas con la misma sintaxis de los modelos o el query builder.. Tinker es una herramienta muy cómoda. Te lo comento porque podrías probar ésta consulta `DB::table('imagen_tag')->select('imagen_id') ->where('tag_id','1')->orWhere('tag_id','2');` pero si no es eso lo que buscas, con tinker te ahorrarás un monton de tiempo hasta poder encontrar lo que buscas.
Pero creo que pasarle un array en la clausula where no está bien.. Hay maneras de hacer que se evalúen dos condiciones en la consulta. Lee sobre las [consultas en laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)

Comment: Para empezar, lo siento el código que había puesto al principio estaba a medias se copio mal y  a lo mejor te ha liado,  y lo segundo es que lo que yo busco (basándome n lo que as puesto de ejemplo) es que sean And y no OR, es decir que cumpla todas las peticiones que le pase